What is C minus infinitely many disjoint "Jordan Balls" conformally equivalent to?
So I recently came across a Theorem due to Koebe proved in 1918 that states that an M connected domain $\mathbb{D}$ in $\mathbb{C}$, that is a a domain such that $\partial \mathbb{D}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}\Gamma_i$ where $\Gamma_i$ are Jordan curves is conformally equivalent to an M connected circular domain, that is a domain $D$ such that $\partial D=\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}B(z_i,r)$ and the conformal map is unique up $f(z)=z+O(1/z)$. The original paper that this proved is in German so if somebody knows sources (ideally a book) where this is proved please guide me. Also can this be generalized to domains that are $\infty$ connected ?

If $\mathcal{D}\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a domain such that $\partial \mathcal{D}=\bigcup_{i=1}^n \Gamma_i$ (where $\Gamma_i$ are disjoint Jordan curves such that none is contained in the interior of another) does it still hold that $\mathcal{D}$ is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{C}- \bigcup_{i}^{\infty}B(z_i,r)$
